# Finding the maximum value in a column of a txt file in Python

Tags: python, max

I am trying to find the maximum value in a column of a txt file in python. So far, I have this code:

```
    file=open('3human_evolution.txt','r')
    lines=file.readlines()
    pos=lines[0].find('Adult')
    print(pos)
```

this gives the position of the column that I want to count. I know I have to either strip or split each line and then append the values to a new list but I am unsure of how to do this.

```
    Species              Lived when      Adult        Adult       Brain volume 

    -------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    H. habilis           2.2 - 1.6       1.0 - 1.5    33 - 55     660
    H. erectus           1.4 - 0.2                    60          850 (early) - 1100 (late)
    H. ergaster          1.9 - 1.4       1.9                      700 - 850
    H. heidelbergensis   0.6 - 0.35      1.8          60          1100 - 1400
    H. neanderthalensis  0.35 - 0.03     1.6          55 - 70     1200 - 1700
    H. sapiens sapiens   0.2 - present   1.4 - 1.9    50 - 100    1000 - 1850
    H. floresiensis      0.10 - 0.012    1.0          25          400
    -------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Comment: can you share what the input file looks like?

Comment: Given that there are two columns named Adult and some of the values in them are ranges, you need to add more clarification as to what the "max" is.

Comment: The first "adult" is supposed to be adult height and the second one is adult mass. I cannot figure out how to find the maximum adult height.